# Cancel execution of POST request

Tags: php, wordpress, api

When creating my API for a website, I created a POST method for updating the user's data.

For convenience and network issues, I tried cancelling the request.

The POST method is still being executed even though the web client has cancelled it. For example, sending the request in Postman then cancelling it. Or even from the website, press Save then refresh the page.

The body of the POST method is being executed either ways.

Is there any way to stop the execution of the body when the request is cancelled?

Comment: How do you make `POST` request? Are you making it **asynchronously** using `JavaScript`.

Comment: Android, Retrofit, OkHttp3, RxJava

Comment: I'm using POST to request a notice be shown to the user on top of (modal to) the home page. So I want the POST to work only once and then be canceled. Then, if the user clicks Refresh, the home page will refresh normally without showing the notice. I can't find a way to do this in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

No. You can't cancel POST request once it is placed from a web client (browser/postman).

As a Client-Server Model once POST request is placed it is treated as a request from a client to the server. And then if you again canceling it by supposing refreshing a web page it is again treated as a next page refresh request.

Comment: I'm sure that's right. But my situation is: user tries to edit their data while offline, or the request takes too long to finish. And the user wishes to cancel the request.

Comment: In Postman, if we do cancel, either way, the request will be executed in the server-side.?
But it won't run again from the postman right..!!!

Comment: this is where postman forked up